# Need to lookup part data when there are multiple rows of the same part

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, wincc

I have a SQL Table that has parts with their own 2D barcodes. There may be multiple rows of the same part. Each row has a column with the Date_Time stamp.

What I need is to get the latest part data and view one of the columns to see if that value is INT 1.

Example below: Look up the latest timestamp for part "5" and see if "PartStatusSt1" is '1'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ00n.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb3Hn.png)

Here is my query:

```
"select * from [AppsData].[dbo].[OilPumpCoverTest] where [2DMatrix] like '" & HMIRuntime.Tags("2DMatrix").Read(1) & "'"
```

Then I need to look at column name "PartStatusSt1" and move that INT value to a WinCC Tag as described below:

```
HMIRuntime.Tags("Sql_Station1_Status").Write
Recordset.Fields("PartStatusSt1").Value,1
```

The code above works but it grabs a random row of part data if I have multiple rows of the same part (via 2DMatrix). I need to grab the latest data per Date_Time stamp.

NOTE: My code is in WinCC via VBS.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your query, and explain what part of the query isn't giving you the results you expect

Comment: Also, please add a tag on your question for the specific type of sql you're working with (oracle, ms-sql, mysql, etc)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"select top 1 * 
from [AppsData].[dbo].[OilPumpCoverTest] 
where [2DMatrix] like '" & HMIRuntime.Tags("2DMatrix").Read(1) & "' order by Date_Time desc "
```

Comment: Select the latest row of data every time

Comment: That makes it even easier! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest part records, I'd start by using RANK to assign a number to each part based on its time stamp.  For example, if part A has three time stamps, each record would be assigned rank 1, 2, and 3, depending on your sorting. I do something similar for the part numbers I work with.  To get the latest records for parts, you can then query all where rankval = 1.
Small sample below...

```
SELECT  z.* 
FROM
(SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PartNo, LotNumber ORDER BY DatePosted DESC) AS rankval                                                            , TagNo, PartNo, LotNumber, DatePosted FROM PartTable) AS z
--WHERE z.rankval = 1
```

You could then use a case statement or where clause to check for the part or part status.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: So below is how i modified your code above and it seems to be working great! Thank you very much!!

Comment: SELECT  z.* 
FROM
(SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [2DMatrix]  ORDER BY [Date_Time] DESC) AS rankval, [2DMatrix], [PartStatusSt1], [Date_Time]  FROM [AppsData].[dbo].[OilPumpCoverTest]) AS z
WHERE z.rankval = 1 and [2DMatrix] like 'Test'

Comment: Very cool, looks great.  Glad I could help!